# @Controller annotation isn't properly mapping Spring Security 4 login page

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {   
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureForwardUrl("/login?error")
                .successForwardUrl("/admin")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

The above `WebSecurityConfig` only works when mapped with the following class:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

When I try and replace the above mapping with a controller, the login request isn't handled properly and get the following error:

`ERROR 290168 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception`

Here's what my controller looks like:

```
@Controller
public class AdminController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Any idea why the `AdminController` request mapping doesn't work while the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` mapping does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. It wasn't with the mapping it was with the `WebSecurityConfig`. Something weird is going on with the `.failureForwardUrl()` method. Here's what I found:

---

The following fails to run completely, resulting in the error I saw

```
.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/loginProcess")
    .successForwardUrl("/admin")
    .failureForwardUrl("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
```

---

With an invalid login, the following code will leave the user at /loginProcess

```
.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/loginProcess")
    .successForwardUrl("/admin")
    .failureForwardUrl("/")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
```

---

With an invalid login, the following code will leave the user at /login?error

```
.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/loginProcess")
    .successForwardUrl("/admin")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
```